# Как из php скрипта передать параметр в дргой php скрипт?

Tags: php

Вопрос вот в чем. имеется ссылка такого типа

```
 <a
 href="index.cgi?year=2013&month=all">2013
 </a>
```

она запускает скрипт и передает в него параметры. Мне это надо переделать , должен запускаться мой скрип на РНР.
Поэтому два вопроса, что нужно указать в первой РНР скрипте для передачи и что нужно указать во втором РНР скрипте для приема этого параметра.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="myscript.php?year=2013&month=all">2013</a>
```

В myscript.php:

```
print $_GET['year'];//выведет год 
print $_GET['month'];// выведет месяц
```